# Get innerHTML of another element on :hover using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, dhtml

I'm working with a platform that does not support onmouseover or onmouseout.  I need to change the innerHTML of another element using JavaScript.  I thought I could probably do this with :hover, but if there is a better CSS/HTML method, I'll go for it.  How would I correlate JavaScript and CSS to get this to work?

Basically,

```
<div id="trigger">To hover over</div>
<div id="dynamicContent">To change innerHTML of</div>
```

Any suggestions on how this might get done using the template above?  Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't it support onmouseover or onmouseout? And what have you tried?

Comment: onmouseover and onmouseout are javascript events which aren't supported by early versions of Google Gadget APIs, so I don't want to use them--that's what I'm developing in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.querySelector("#trigger").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    var txt = document.querySelector("#dynamicContent").innerHTML;
    document.querySelector("#dynamicContent").innerHTML = "Changed.";

    this.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
        document.querySelector("#dynamicContent").innerHTML = txt;
    });
});
```

`:)`

Comment: The question says that the platform does not support `onmouseover` or `onmouseout`.

Comment: @dunsmoreb - He is making that Google Gadget thing. (Not sure)

Comment: thing.  Yes, this was building off the previous question.  You are NOT stupid :D    As you can see, I'm on line 976 of 10,247 of version 4.1 and am just stuck (but almost there)!

Comment: Note that [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) is only supported in IE8+, nevertheless +1 for the jQuery-translated code.